# How can I set the position of images on a web page based on Javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this basic HTML code that inserts an image on the screen in a specific position:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <img src="myImage.png" 
       style="position:fixed; right:300px; bottom:300px; width:100px; height:100px;" />
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to change my `right` and `bottom` parameters based on variables that I've declared in my Javascript code. The following block of code is a pseudo code that represents the idea of what I want to do:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <img src="myImage.png" 
       style="position:fixed; id="rightposition"; id="bottomposition"; width:100px; height:100px;" />
      <script>
         var right="right:"+200+"px";
         var bottom="bottom:"+200+"px";
         document.getElementById("rightposition").style = right; 
         document.getElementById("bottomposition").style = bottom; 
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I define the position of my image based on the two variables that I've declared on my Javascript code?

Comment: The second block of code is not even valid HTML.

Comment: @GrantGryczan I know this is a very basic question... When I run this page I see my image on the position top=0 and left=0, that's why I said that it didn't work. But when you say that it's not a valid HTML you mean the same that CertainPerformance said on his answer? That it doesn't work because I'm using the id inside an element attribute?

Comment: Yes. Just do what CertainPerformance said, and then maybe look into HTML syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the element and then assign to its `style` property. Note that only *elements themselves* can have `id`s - element *attributes* (such as in your HTML) cannot.

```js
var right = 100 + "px";
var bottom = 100 + "px";
const img = document.querySelector('#img');
img.style.right = right;
img.style.bottom = bottom;
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1" style="position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px;" />
```

Comment: Thanks!! That worked... Can I assume that the syntax of your answer can be used with different element attributes as well? Not just with the style?

Comment: For the most part, yes, though for a few you'll have to use `setAttribute` instead, or the name may be different, eg assign to `image.className`. But those situations are unusual.